# Using scikit-learn NMF with a precomputed set of basis vectors (Python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nmf

I want to use scikit-learn NMF (from [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html)) (or any other NMF if it does the job, actually).

Specifically, I have an input matrix (which is an audio magnitude spectrogram), and I want to decompose it.

I already have the W matrix pre-computed. How do I use a **fixed W** in `sklearn.decompose.NMF`? I haven't found any other question asking this.

I see that [this](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.decompose.decompose.html) method also mentions something similar in the *fit* parameter: "If False, components are assumed to be pre-computed and stored in transformer, and are not changed.". However, I am not sure how to make that transformer object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This part of the code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/decomposition/nmf.py#L639) explains internal processing a bit.

It sounds you want to fix W. According to the code, you can only fix H, while optimizing W. That's not a problem, as you can just switch those matrices (invert their roles).

Doing this, the code says: use `init='custom'` and set `update_h=False`.

So in general i would expect usage to look like (based on the example [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html)):

Untested!

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,1], [2, 1], [3, 1.2], [4, 1], [5, 0.8], [6, 1]])

fixed_W = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1])  # size=3 just an example
                                                                      # might break
fixed_H = fixed_W.T  # interpret W as H (transpose)

from sklearn.decomposition import NMF
model = NMF(n_components=2, init='custom', H=fixed_H, update_H=False, random_state=0)
model.fit(X)
```

You probably want to switch your variables after solving again.

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, the untested code above won't work.
We need to use the more low-level function available to do that.

Here is a quick hack (where i don't care much about the right preprocessing; transpose and co.) which should make you able to tackle your task:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,1], [2, 1], [3, 1.2], [4, 1], [5, 0.8], [6, 1]])

fixed_W = np.array([[0.4,0.4],[0.2,0.1]])  # size=2 just an example
fixed_H = fixed_W.T  # interpret W as H (transpose)

from sklearn.decomposition import NMF, non_negative_factorization

W, H, n_iter = non_negative_factorization(X, n_components=2, init='random', random_state=0)
print(W)
print(H)
print('error: ')
print(W.dot(H) - X)  # just a demo, it's not the loss minimized!

W, H, n_iter = non_negative_factorization(X, n_components=2, init='custom', random_state=0, update_H=False, H=fixed_H)
print(W)
print(H)
print('error: ')
print(W.dot(H) - X)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.          0.46880684]
 [ 0.55699523  0.3894146 ]
 [ 1.00331638  0.41925352]
 [ 1.6733999   0.22926926]
 [ 2.34349311  0.03927954]
 [ 2.78981512  0.06911798]]
[[ 2.09783018  0.30560234]
 [ 2.13443044  2.13171694]]
error: 
[[  6.35579822e-04  -6.36528773e-04]
 [ -3.40231372e-04   3.40739354e-04]
 [ -3.45147253e-04   3.45662574e-04]
 [ -1.31898319e-04   1.32095249e-04]
 [  9.00218123e-05  -9.01562192e-05]
 [  8.58722020e-05  -8.60004133e-05]]
[[  3.           0.        ]
 [  5.           0.        ]
 [  4.51221142   2.98707026]
 [  0.04070474   9.95690087]
 [  0.          12.23529412]
 [  0.          14.70588235]]
[[ 0.4  0.2]
 [ 0.4  0.1]]
error: 
[[  2.00000000e-01  -4.00000000e-01]
 [ -2.22044605e-16  -1.11022302e-16]
 [ -2.87327549e-04   1.14931020e-03]
 [ -9.57758497e-04   3.83103399e-03]
 [ -1.05882353e-01   4.23529412e-01]
 [ -1.17647059e-01   4.70588235e-01]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it seems like `H=fixed_H` is an unexpected keyword argument.

Comment: @pk1914 You are right. We need to use some other function available.

Comment: Seems great! I should also mention that I also had to transpose the `X` array.

Comment: I was confused at first, and realized what is happening. Sklearn can only solve `X=WH` while keeping the second matrix, `H` fixed. To  deal with this, sascha solved `X^T=H^T W^T`, making sklearn keep the second matrix, now `W^T` fixed, solving for `H^T`. Very clever!

Comment: @pavlos163 you can use H=fixed_H when you use sklearn.decomposition.non_negative_factorization rather than .NMF and then it works.